# Question about a terminology which implements something like this list.Add(new{a=1, b=2})

Tags: linq

What is the terminology for the usage of "new" in:

```
 list.Add(new{a=1, b=2})
```

And what type should I replace the T in List  getList if I want to use the list as the returned value? I don't want to replace T with "object" because I want to parse it in Linq query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not specify a type: `new {1`), it's called object initializers with anonymous types.  ([MSDN Explaining them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx))  The Object Initializer part is where you do `{ a=1, b=2}`.

If you want to be able to reference a type, you will have to create a type and stuff the values in.

```
list.Add(
  new MyType() {
         a=1, 
         b=2 
 });
```

If you are just going to be pairing two items look into using the [Pair Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair.aspx).  There is also a [Triplet Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.triplet.aspx) just in case you might want to store 3 items.